# py3o odoo odt make sure it has been added with the set_image_path or set_image_data methods

Tags: python, report, odoo-10, odt

I have an error when I want to print my invoice_report with **py3o** system

> TemplateException: Can't find data for the image named
>   'py3o.staticimage.logo'; make sure it has been added with the
>   set_image_path or set_image_data methods.

its seems that a python object is not recognized by the **py3o** template

Anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: I think we're going to need some more info. here!

Comment: I use **py3o report engine** for a **odt** output report in odoo10,when I want to print the report I have that error,so I want to know the right process to create one